# Batch variables are broken

Tags: batch-file

I am making  chat room kind of thing in batch. Unfortunately the file fails to store variables. Here is my code

```
@echo off
color b
Title Messanger
:top
echo Are you hosting the chat?
set /p host="Yes or no>"
if /i "%host%"=="yes" (
    set /p port="Port>"
    rem This would normally listen for connections
    echo Listening for connections on port %port%
    pause
 )
if /i "%host%"=="no" (
    echo Who is hosting this chat?
    set /p ip="Ip>"
    set /p port="Port>"
    echo ----------------CHAT----------------
    rem This would normally connect to the ip and port
    echo %ip% %port%
 )
echo Error.
pause
goto top
```

I dont know if you get the same result but only see the message without the variables. OUTPUT:

```
Are you hosting the chat?
Yes or no>yes
Port>8080
Listening for connections on port
Press any key to continue . . .
```

After this it does as it should ad echos error and goes to the start of the file

Comment: Which exact part is not working? I don't have access to a Windows machine but can probably still help if you tell me the desired vs achieved results. Is it the `IF` statement that is failing and not taking the right route, or is it the `%ip%` & `%port%` that are not showing up in the `echo`?

Comment: it is saying that the variables dont have any value when they should take up the value of the input. EDIT: just saw the edit on the comment. the %ip% and %port% are not showing up in the echo

Comment: So the `IF` statement is not evaluating properly? Or is that working, and it is the `%ip%` and `%port%` that are not showing up in the `echo`?

Comment: Perhaps you can add the output to your question body.

Comment: i can add the output of if i selected no if that helps

Comment: Thanks! Please see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is two-fold:

1) You need to add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the beginning of your script. Like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color b
Title Messanger
```

(Note line 2)

2) Then, inside the `IF` blocks, you need to address your variables with `!` instead of `%`, like this:

```
if /i "%host%"=="yes" (
    set /p port="Port>"
    rem This would normally listen for connections
    echo Listening for connections on port !port!
    pause
 )
```

(Note line 4)

### Explanation

Because `%ip%` and `%port%` are inside a clause (i.e. within parentheses), their values get captured before the actual code inside the block executes. Before the interpreter enters the `IF` block, it captures the value of `%port%` before doing that (which doesn't exist before it enters the actual block). So, while it *looks* like your code was running

```
echo Listening for connections on port %port%
```

What was actually running is

```
echo Listening for connections on port
```

(Note the empty space. `%port%` got replaced with the value of `%port%` *before* it entered the block within the parentheses - which is an empty value.

The solution for working with variables that get modified and then re-used within one block is to enable delayed expansion and then use the `!` symbol instead of `%` to reference them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Will love to see this explanation. Forgot to add that this fixed the issue

Comment: Great!! Let me know if the explanation makes sense or if you have any other questions. Also, feel free to mark as answer if the solution ended up working correctly.

Comment: If I got a dollar for every time someone posted a question where the reason the code isn't working is because of delayed Expansion, I'd still be nothing richer because I'm not american and we don't use dollars here.